# Asp.net mvc url routing. Change url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing, asp.net-routing

My controller is "/Home/Index".I want, when i  type url to "/Dashboard/Index" or "example.com/Dashboard"  my "/Home/Index action method" executed. Can you give me starting point?

Comment: Try changing the name of HomeController to DashboardController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this route to your route config. Make sure to add it *before* the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "HomeRoute",
    url: "Dashboard/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```